# Is it possible to get direct access to PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have seen products like InfluxDB that extend PostgreSQL. Those products suggest that they use PostgreSQL in a direct way (accessing the data in its primitive form, without SQL).

However googling for “direct access to PostgreSQL” and similar questions I get no useful information.

So, is it possible to access PostgreSQL directly (like using a C++ library) without any SQL? If so, how?

Comment: *"Those products sugegest that they use PostgreSQL in a direct way"* - can you provide a link to such claim?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/metrics-to-monitor-in-your-postgresql-database/) at the Read/Write Throughput section. At least I infer that they have some sort of direct access.

Comment: `pg_stat_*` are views accessed via SQL. These are virtual views that show various database engine statistics - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html (e.g. `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` to see active database connections).

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera The link you provide does not claim anything like direct access to the data files.

Comment: @SantiPeñate-Vera *why* do you want to bypass SQL? What is the *actual* problem you think can be solved by bypassing SQL? And what kind of "direct" access do you want? Do you want to bypass buffered data and load from disk using slow IO?

Comment: Hi, I work in real time control systems and some vendors have a "database" that you can access via C primitive types. I was thinking that maybe that was a possibility in PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write a user defined function in C, you can have direct access to the data in the data files.

But unless you are out to produce data corruption, you will have to follow PostgreSQL's protocols, consider visibility, take and respect locks and so on, so you'd better use PostgreSQL's API.

For example, you could bypass the query parser and optimizer and directly write an index scan on a table. But then you can get almost the same performance if you use a prepared statement.

Bypassing SQL is probably not a smart idea in most cases, but you can use the [server programming interface](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi.html) to run SQL from C code inside the backend to avoid client-server round trips.